# Getting access denied when using AWTEventListener in Applet

Tags: java, swing, security, applet, awt

I have an applet embedded in browser. In the applet `init()` method I have the below code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if(event instanceof MouseEvent){
                MouseEvent evt = (MouseEvent)event;
                if(evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED){
                    System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
                }
            }
        }
    }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

When applet loads I'm getting error:

```
access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "listenToAllAWTEvents")
```

### Policy

Now in my policy file (path below) I appended at the bottom:

#### Permission

```
grant  {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

#### Path

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/security/java.policy
```

But I'm still getting same access denied problem.

Anyone has any idea why I'm still getting that error even though I'm granting all permissions in the `java.policy` file?

Comment: *"I have the below code:"*  Why?  What are you trying to achieve by that?  *"Now in my "..java.policy"* Don't mess with policy files, they are not a practical way to deploy an applet with extended permissions.  The applet needs to be digitally signed if it is to do things like that.

Comment: I'm just  trying to add my own global mouse listener.  This will avoid having me to write a mouse listener to each individual component.

Comment: I as an end user would be unwilling to allow extended permissions to anyone just for getting events from all applets in the same JVM.  Do a recursive call on components in your applet and add listeners, or better still, look into things like the `Action` API & key bindings.

Comment: Thanks for that link, it now works. I was modifying the wrong java.policy file.  I agree applet should be signed, but this is what we currently have in place. Also this applet is deployed in an internal network with few users.  I also narrowed permission down to "listenToAllAWTEvents".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to trusted code written/deployed by me. It produces the [`java.home` property](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.home&trusted=on&format=TSV) for the JVM.

Here it points to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

Note that no part of that path contains `jdk` as I now note in the path above. Ensure the policy file is on the same path as the one identified in the applet.